# Network communication in main UI thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, networking

I have following concern..

My application downloads 6 MB of data when it is started for the first time.
During that process `UIView` with information about ongoing download is presented, and generally there is no interaction with user.

Because of that I do all downloading of data in main UI Thread, using `dispatch_async`, but now I don't know if this is the best solution and what will Apple say when I will submit my application.

Could you please guide my if this is Ok or not ?

**Update**
Dispatch code

```
//Called at the end of [UIViewController viewDidLoad]
-(void)splashScreenAppeared
{
myTabBarController_.loadingLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Checking for updates",@"launch progress");
dispatch_queue_t d_queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
[self launchActionCheckIfDataIsStored:d_queue];
}
//...
-(void)launchActionCheckIfDataIsStored:(dispatch_queue_t)queue
{
dispatch_async(queue, ^ {
    //If there is no data stored in core data then download xml data files and images
    if (![self isAnyDataStoredInCoreData]) {
        launchNoDataStored_ = YES;
        [self launchDownloadData:queue];
    } else {
        launchNoDataStored_ = NO;
        [self launchCheckNewVersion:queue];
    }

});
}
//...
-(void)launchDownloadData:(dispatch_queue_t)queue
{        
myTabBarController_.loadingLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Downloading catalog data",@"launch progress");
dispatch_async(queue, ^ {
    [self loadMenuData];
    if (seriousError_) {
        [self launchSeriousError:queue];
        return;
    }

    myTabBarController_.loadingLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Downloading products details",@"launch progress");
    dispatch_async(queue, ^ {
        [self loadProductsData];
        if (seriousError_) {
            [self launchSeriousError:queue];
            return;
        }
//...
//And so on with other parts of download
}
```

Comment: Post your dispatch code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to set the background, I have written & submitted 2 successful apps to the App Store, so you know that I am not hypothesizing.

Coming back, you can push the download to a background thread and update the progress in the form of a slider (for the benefit of the user). But if in this scenario the user does not get to do anything anyway then there is no point.

Plus I dont think Apple would reject your app just 'coz of this. One of the main things they check is if you are using any Private API's or something more basic like app crashes. So go ahead and submit for APP store review...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but for some reasons my application crashes at startup when I run it from Xcode. Previously it worked fine.. Ehh

Comment: Heh, it seems that I signed my app not with correct provisioning profile. Recently I changed provisioning profile to release so it could be made as **ipa** for test purposes. Jupi :)

Answer (score 0):

Now I know that network communication in UI Thread can be a good reason to reject your application by Apple.

Consider the following scenario:

- Application is for iPhone.
- There is no interaction with user.
- Application is run on iPad!!

Even though there is no interaction with user, application does not react when user presses **2x** button on iPad.

So network communication in UI thread works, but if application is not for iPad only, then application will be rejected in Apple review process.